# Compare AD groups with CSV File in Powershell

Tags: csv, active-directory, powershell-3.0

We are undergoing a migration at work.  We have a CSV file which in column A has the legacy AD group name, and column B has the new group name.

I want to be able to obtain group membership of a given user, compare those results with Column A in CSV and then output a list of which groups the user should be a part of going forward.

It works in my head however even a pointer to where to even begin would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the Microsoft Gallery for you because I found this question interesting.  What I found was not exactly what you were looking for, but was the closest to it out of 188 different items.  It's at least, a start.   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Determine-the-Differences-7f82e8c2